# Dual of a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space. Is there any way to explicitly compute the expression of norm of $X^*$ using the norm of $X$?

For example, consider the Banach space $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ equppied with the norm

$$\|(x,y)\|=\max\{|x|,|y|,|f(x,y)|\}$$

where $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.

Now, what is the dual norm of the above norm, i.e., for an element $(a,b)\in X^*$, how to find
$\|(a,b)\|_{X^*}$?

Comment: What you defined will generally not be a norm. Take $f(x,y)=x\cdot y$. Then $\|(2,2)\|=4\neq 2=2\|(1,1)\|$.